# Why do I keep randomly losing bits of reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, recent-activity, reputation-history

This is the second time this has happened.  Granted, it isn't the end of the world, but a little shocking when I find I had 1,266 rep, then a day later, 1,206.

I've checked my activity thoroughly, and not 1 action there which deducted my reputation.

anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947072/how-to-add-text-in-a-png-file-with-html/16947147#16947147) was deleted along with the question “How to Add Text in a PNG File with HTML”:

> When an image is saved, it uses algorithms to tell where the pixels
>   should be. (try editing a .png in notepad, you'll see what i mean)
>
> You cannot do this with HTML. HTML is a markup language. All it knows
>   how to do is display. The only ways i can think of doing what you want
>   to do, it to either re-export an image, or use a server-side script to
>   inject text in.
>
> …

It had 6 upvotes, and you lost the 60 reputation you gained.

Comment: That would explain it!

Comment: @sircapsalot: You should be able to see it (without a link) [on your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1695163/sircapsalot?tab=reputation&sort=post), if I recall correctly. (If not — I’m a moderator. `=)`)

Comment: nope, can't see it, like i said - i looked around, ha :)   alright!  thanks man

Comment: @sircapsalot: Did you check “show removed posts” at the bottom? I’m not sure why that’s even an option, but…

Comment: sure enough - it's there.. thanks for that